# UEFI vs. ARM TrustZone

Tags: windows-8, arm, tpm, secure-boot, tee

I understand UEFI has a Secure Boot feature that is now for all Win 8 (tablets, and smartphones). How does this fit in with AMR's TrustZone for example? Is UEFI like a firmware TPM that can sit as a Trusted App in TrustZone's Normal Domain after the TrustZone TEE has loaded the Secure Domain? I am unclear how these two fit together - or perhaps they are competing technologies??

Comment: TPM can exist on X86 hardware but its not required.  They don't fit together nor are they competing technologies.

Comment: Ok, thanks Ramhound. So would Intel/McAfee's DeepSafe be the alternative competitor to TrustZone? I read last week that it will be available for Windows 8 and Android OS. I did not see many details about how it woudl work other than it sits in the kernel (still I don't think its a TEE really).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't go into any controversies that surround UEFI, Secure boot or TPM in general (out of scope), so I'll try and answer as directly as possible.

[UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) is (for all intents and purposes) a BIOS 'replacement' that sits at the BIOS level (between hardware and OS). [UEFI Secure boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot) has to be supported by the firmware (BIOS); UEFI Secure boot is essentially a way to prevent 'unsigned' code from booting, as of right now Windows 8, Windows Server 2012 and certain Linux distributions have signed UEFI secure boot keys that are able to use the feature.

[TPM (trusted platform module)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) is a standard that is usually implemented as a separated hardware module that can be used to generate crypto keys (among other things). It is not the same as UEFI (nor are they of related organizational groups); TPM is a hardware level crypto that is used for things like full disk encryption and DRM and has to be physically installed as a separate module (though many new PC/laptops/motherboards include the option to come pre-installed with a hardware TPM) where as UEFI sits between the hardware and the OS itself. Technically speaking, one could use UEFI (Secure boot) with a TPM. TPM's are manufactured by many different companies. UEFI is firmware that is 'manufactured' (coded) by a few companies as well.

UEFI and TPM are (typically) found only on x86/x64 platforms (i.e. Intel/AMD/PPC CPU/chipsets). ARM (a competing CPU/chip maker to Intel and AMD) offers something similar to a UEFI/TPM setup and that's their [TrustZone](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/trustzone/index.php). TrustZone is something that is built into the ARM chips themselves it's slightly different in that UEFI is at the BIOS and TPM is 'baked' into hardware modules, but ARM's TrustZone can be utilized 'system wide'; the idea being that you have a mixture of UEFI/TPM type functionality in each device that has an ARM chipset in it (which could be anything from a keyboard/mouse to a monitor and printer).

One thing to note with ALL of these technologies is that at a software level, most of the 'secure' functionality needs to be implemented in order to be used. For instance, you could have a PC with a TPM and use TrueCrypt for full disk encryption (TrueCrypt does not support TPM). This is the same with ARM's TrustZone; the system/software integrator needs to take advantage of those capabilities for it to be effective/work (in other words, just because something is physically on your machine does not mean it's 'active').

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. That was really helpful.

Comment: No problem! And should anyone else stumble upon this feel free to edit for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - Trustzone gives primitives to implement UEFI and TPM functionality on an ARM CPU.

Additional features/primitives needed are,

- secure boot
- crypto processor
- tampers
- RTC
- Persistent storage that erases/invalidates on tamper

The last three features require constant power to those elements.  Tampers may extend to a chip level mesh.  Some AMD systems have an ARM CPU for these reasons.

---

*txtechhelp* answer is interesting and I believe he gives an *x86* perspective.  **TrustZone** at the lowest level is a mechanism to partition ARM software into two *worlds*.  One is the *secure world* and the other is the *normal world*.  It is never a complete solution by itself.  The ARM licensee (Freescale, Samsung, TI, Apple, BroadCom, etc) must provide hooks to complete the solution.  For instance the **TZASC**, is a bus controller that is **TrustZone** aware.  The gist of this is that [**DMA attacks**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMA_attack) in a sufficiently configured system are not possible.

In order to configure the *bus controller* and the *secure world*, by necessity TrustZone boots in *secure mode*.  This implies that any system that tries to implement security with TrustZone has **secure boot**.

From the description of UEFI, if anyone has an exploit for a signed kernel, then they can steal secrets either directly or by using a DMA device (side-steps MMU).  If the secrets are not accessible via the bus, then this is not possible.  *TrustZone* tries to allow two sets of code to run.  So an *unsigned* version of Linux maybe used with *Trusted code* which does a secure boot and sets up the *bus controller* to restrict *bus masters* and *slaves*.  This *Trusted code* may just be a set of routines which does authentication and encryption/decryption as per a TPM; there must also be some hardware to provide protected secret keys in this case.

The *trusted code* should be a minimum set of functionality.  It may be an OS or simply a set of routines/API depending on the requirements.  Just as with UEFI, an exploit here can subvert security.  However, as the footprint should be minimal/reduced, the *attack vectors* should be smaller.

See: [TrustZone Whitepaper](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.prd29-genc-009492c/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Many ARM systems contain *TrustZone*, but the *licensee* didn't care to use it.  So it is very common to have a Cortex cellphone with TrustZone, but it will not boot securely nor make use of TrustZone.

Comment: Since this post, there is 'Arm trusted firmware' and 'TEE' for 'secure' library calls.  TEE gives features like, encode block with private key, where private key can not be read, but the device can encrypt arbitrary data to prove it is authentic.  Also, trustzone is used in some AMD CPU to actually accomplish secure boot and would be part of the UEFI hierarchy in those chip sets.